# How to find matching text in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have develop faq page like this,
[image]

There are 6 main categories and for each category have sub categories. For each main category i have a page with all the questions divide into separate div classes like this,

[image]

When someone search text in main page if it match to question i want it to load under search bar like this,
[image]

Can someone help me to fix this?

I done this code but it only search main page,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init()
    {

        var text = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + text + "\\b)", "gim");
        var e = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer").innerHTML;
        var enew = e.replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
        document.getElementById("myBtnContainer").innerHTML = enew;
        var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span>$1</span>");
        document.getElementById("myBtnContainer").innerHTML = newe;
    }
</script>
```

**This is how i code questions,**

```
<div class="membershipB">
    <div class="faq_container">
        <div class="faq">
            <div class="faq_question">Whats the difference between a Hot Desk and a Fixed Desk? <div style="float: right; color: #194239;" class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></div></div>
            <div class="faq_answer_boarder">
                <div class="faq_answer_container">
                    <div class="faq_answer">A Hot Desk is any desk within the hot desking area and has a minimum sign-up period of one (1) month. You will  enjoy flexibility here as you get the chance to change your seat everyday. <br>
                        A Fixed Desk is a reserved seat and has a minimum sign-up period of three (3) months. Members can set up their desktops and their desks come with drawers that can be locked.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <hr class="hr">
        <div class="faq">
            <div class="faq_question">How do I change my membership plan? <div style="float: right; color: #194239;" class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></div></div>
            <div class="faq_answer_boarder">
                <div class="faq_answer_container">
                    <div class="faq_answer">
                        <p>
                            Whether you're expanding or downsizing your company, we got you! Get in touch with our friendly  <a href="mailto:info@commonground.work">  Sales team  </a>  at info@commonground.work, and they will do their best to find a solution for you.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**This how i show specific sub category questions inside page,**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.membershipH').hide();
        $('.virtualH').hide();
        $('.helloH').hide();
        $('.primeH').hide();

        $('.membershipB').hide();
        $('.virtualB').hide();
        $('.helloB').hide();
        $('.primeB').hide();

        var type = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

        if(type == 'membership')
        {
            $('.membershipH').show();
            $('.membershipB').show();
        }
        else if(type == 'virtualoffice')
        {
            $('.virtualH').show();
            $('.virtualB').show();
        }
        else if(type == 'hellocg')
        {
            $('.helloH').show();
            $('.helloB').show();
        }
        else
        {
            $('.primeH').show();
            $('.primeB').show();
        }
```

**Can someone help me to fix this?**

Comment: Do you have an example set of data? It's hard to see what you have and what you using as a reference at the moment. Are the pictures a mix between inspiration & your work?

Comment: Can you do a server-side search? Searching multiple pages is best done server side.

Comment: @Nathan i update question with code. Phone  image is design i need to developed. other images are i already developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the other pages in some hidden iframes and search inside them, for example:

```
<iframe id="membership-plans-iframe" src="/membership-plans" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

And then you could search inside the iframe content:

```
var anotherPageText = document.getElementById('membership-plans-iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('yourTextInsideMembershipPlans').value;
```

It's a little bit dirty as an approach but it works